# ValueError: NumPy boolean array indexing assignment cannot assign 0 input values to the N output values where the mask is true

Tags: python, numpy

I have a Dicom file and i would like to apply a number of masks with different operations in the voxels. However, I would like to keep the positions in the initial array because I want to reconstruct the image. This is what I have done:

```
#The dicom data    
a=dicomm_data.pixel_array
#start function
my_modified_array = np.zeros_like(a)
#mask 1
m1=a[(a>limit_1) & (a<limit_2)]
m1=m1*chosen_number1 + chose_number2
my_modified_array [(a>limit_1) & (a<limit_2)] = m1

#mask 2
m2=a[(a>limit_2+1) & (a<limit_3)]
m2=m1*chosen_number3+chosen_number_4
my_modified_array [(a>limit_2+1) & (a<limit_3)] = m2
```

and I continue with more masks. 
However, I am receiving the mentioned in the title error.
I have read another post which uses the numpy.where function but still cannot fix it.

Comment: What is `a1`?  It suddenly appears in an expression without being mentioned before.

Comment: It is my initial data array. Just correct it.

Comment: Anyone something to propose?

Answer (score 1):

You'll get the error when `m1` is an empty array but `a[(a>limit_2+1) & (a<limit_3)]` is not empty.  I think

```
m2=m1*chosen_number3+chosen_number_4
```

should be

```
m2=m2*chosen_number3+chosen_number_4
```

That's the pattern you used with `m1`, and that would fix the error.

Comment: It worked. Totally my mistake. Thanks. I think I should delete my post.

Comment: It happens.  If the problem was just a typographical error, then sure, it would make sense to delete the question.